# Given p => q, find ¬q=>¬p (statements about polynomials)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm taking a course in a discrete math. The current subject is mathematical logic.

The problem is
**If f is a polynomial of odd degree, then f has at least one real root.
Find ¬q => ¬p.**

I can identify the structure of the proposition as p => q. p is "f is a polynomial of odd degree" and q is "f has at least one real root". The problem is to find ¬q=>¬p. The negation of p (¬p) is "f is a polynomial of even degree". My problem is that I can't figure out have to negate q. Any help will be more than appreciated.

Thanks in advance

PS I hope my English is understandable.

Comment: Small nitpick, the negation of "$f$ is a polynomial of odd degree" is not necessarily "$f$ is a polynomial of even degree". For example, if $f(x)=e^x$ then $f$ is neither an odd polynomial nor an even one.

Comment: Even assuming $f$ is a polynomial, the negation of "$f$ is a polynomial of odd degree" may or may not be "$f$ is a polynomial of even degree", depending on what you consider the degree of $p(x)=0$ to be. It's safest to say "$f$ is not a polynomial of odd degree".

Comment: $p\implies q$ means "If $f$ is a polynomial of odd degree then it has at least one real root".  $\lnot q \implies \not p$ means "If $f$ has no real roots then it is not a polynomial of odd degree".

Comment: @79037662 Isn't $p(x) =0$ a polynomial of zero degree, and isn't zero even?

Comment: @fleablood it's more complicated than that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial#Degree_of_the_zero_polynomial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

$f $ has at least one real root means

$$(\exists a\in \Bbb R) \; : \; f(a)=0$$

the negation is
$f$ has no real root , or

$$(\forall x\in \Bbb R) \;\; f(x)\ne 0$$

Answer (score 0):

The negation of $\ge1$ (at least one) is $\lt1$ (less than one) but we are talking about the number of roots of $f$ hence $0$ is the only possible value i.e. $\lnot q = f$ has no real roots.